# How can I transform HSV to RGB?

Tags: c++, qt

Can you help me how can i change HSV to RGB ?

Comment: Average out the HSV of pixel and slider, adding them could give a value out of range. Also, post some code.

Comment: Yeah, I will write some code, but I need an algorithm what my code should do :(

Comment: Ok, look [here](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/06/05/change-hue-image-qt/) and maybe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936021/shifting-the-hue-of-a-qimage-qpixmap)

Comment: :O thanks a lot, I will try it

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work with my image load as QImage

Comment: Please check my answer :) Thanks

Comment: What have you googled up?

Comment: That: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053541/how-can-i-change-hue-saturation-and-value-of-image

Answer (score 0):

Your color object is probably has setters for the HSV members....

So you need to define the 3 slider to play with the H,S and V values..

remember:

[image]

- **H**ue : the color type (red, blue, or yellow) **Ranges from 0 to 360°**
- **S**aturation : the intensity of the color. **Ranges from 0 to 100%**
- **B**rightness (or Value) : the brightness of the color. **Ranges from 0 to 100%**

---

```
QImage myImage = ....
QColor myColor = myImage.pixelColor(...);
myColor.setHsv(....);
```

Comment: Yeah I have 3 sliders:
H - with range 0-360
, S - with range 0-100 , V - with range 0-100

Comment: But what I should do next? I load image from file as QImage

Comment: QImage myImage = ....
QColor myColor = myImage.pixelColor(...);
myColor.setHsv(....);

Comment: Convert the QRgb values given by imagevar.pixel(pixx, pixy) to HSV, average them with your slider values, revert those values to QRgb variable, use imagevar.setPixe(pixx,pixy, newQRgb) to change those values. *Edit* exactly as @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ says

Comment: Please check my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to shift HS and V over the whole image by a value? Easy enough, centre your sliders at 0 and allow hue to go from -2PI to 2PI, and s and v to go from -1.0 to 1.0. Hue can't go out of range, it wraps to +/- PI or whatever convention you use. S and V are clamped to 0 - 1, (or 0 - 255 if you use bytes instead of floats).

You will need HSVtoRGB and RGBtoHSV, which is readily available on the web.

Comment: Please check my answer :) Thanks